# Selecting DRI device to use with SDL2

Tags: linux, opengl, sdl-2

I have two GPUs in my system, a discrete Amd and an integrated Intel:

```
$ drm_info  | grep Driver:
├───Driver: amdgpu (AMD GPU) version 3.49.0 (20150101)
├───Driver: i915 (Intel Graphics) version 1.6.0 (20201103)
```

I use SDL2 to create my OpenGL context, and SDL lists then following video devices for my system:

```
SDL2 video driver #0: x11
SDL2 video driver #1: wayland
SDL2 video driver #2: KMSDRM
SDL2 video driver #3: offscreen
SDL2 video driver #4: dummy
SDL2 video driver #5: evdev
```

I can pick one, either programmatically, or using the `SDL_VIDEODRIVER` environment variable at run-time.

This enables me to switch between wayland and x11.

But how do I influence SDL2 to pick either the AMD or the Intel GPU?

At the moment it seems to favour the Intel one, even though my main 4K display is connected to the AMD device. It does this under x11 and wayland.

I initialize my video device with this code:

```
const int initerr2 = SDL_InitSubSystem( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
if ( initerr2 ) LOGE( "Failed to initialize video subsystem of SDL2: %s", SDL_GetError() );
```

And I specicify my GL context using these attributes:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 5);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
if ( opt_msaa>0 )
{
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, opt_msaa);
}
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE, 1);
```

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: Logitech BRIO Ultra HD Webcam type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid,uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 44.0 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,radeon,vesa dri: iris gpu: amdgpu,i915 resolution:
    1: 1280x768~60Hz 2: 3840x2160~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.2 renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 770
    (ADL-S GT1)
```

How can I tell SDL2 to choose between `/dev/dri/card0` and `/dev/dri/card1` devices?

Answer (score 0):

SDL2 does not seem to have a mechanism for this, but you can control the GPU selection in the OS instead, using this MESA environment variable:

[DRI_PRIME](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html#envvar-DRI_PRIME)

You can set it to a PCI ID, but also to a vendor:device ID, like so:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1002:67df ./sdl2app
```

The above line will force the application to run on my AMD RX580 instead of on the iGPU.

Comment: There's code in the offscreen backend to use the EGL device/platform selection extensions, but that's not a general solution.